# How to clean vector segment intersect errors in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, vector

I'm using GRASS to process a vector map.
When I export back to .SHP and do a 'Check Geometry Validity' in Quantum GIS it lists several errors of this type...

```
3,segments 199 and 203 of line 0 intersect at 129334.076193, 669460.784787
```

I've tried using v.clean to get rid of them with no effect. Can anyone give me some hints for the correct v.clean tool to use please?

Also is there a vector geometry checker in GRASS so I dont have to keep exporting back to shapefile to check for errors?

Here are the commands I run. The errors start appearing in 'pass2' The map is free of errors prior to import into GRASS (as far as the Quantum GIS checker is concerned at least).

```
v.in.ogr -o dsn=E:/geography/uk2/gb_pass0.shp output=pass0
v.clean input=pass0 output=pass1 --o tool=rmarea,rmdac,rmdupl,rmline thresh=100000
v.generalize input=pass1 output=pass2 --o method=chaiken threshold=100
v.generalize input=pass2 output=pass3 --o type=boundary method=reduction threshold=100 -r
v.generalize input=pass3 output=pass4 --o type=boundary method=douglas threshold=40 -r
v.clean input=pass4 output=pass5 --o tool=prune thresh=40
v.clean input=pass5 output=pass6 --o type=area tool=rmarea thresh=7000000
v.clean input=pass6 output=pass7 --o tool=rmdangle,break,rmdupl thresh=1000
v.clean input=pass7 output=pass8 --o tool=rmbridge,rmsa,rmdac,bpol,rmdupl
v.clean input=pass8 output=pass9 --o tool=break,rmdupl,rmline
v.centroids input=pass9 output=pass10 --o
v.out.ogr input=pass10@mapset1 type=area layer=1 format=ESRI_Shapefile dsn=E:/geography/uk2/gb_boundary olayer=gb_boundary -e
```

Comment: Which GRASS version do you use?

Comment: @markusN Grass 6.4.0 (it came with QGIS v1.6.0). On windows7 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

There have been fixes for v.generalize in [GRASS GIS 6.4.1](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/6.4.1-News) but I am not sure if that would help in your case. If you can, please [install latest winGRASS 6.4.svn](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/) and try.

If it still fails, we would appreciate a [bug report](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/) with a reproducible example. In this forum, bug reports get rather lost.

Comment: For the record, a bunch of more fixes for v.generalize have been backported now from GRASS 7 to GRASS 6.4.svn, they will be published in GRASS 6.4.2 (or grab again a recent SVN version).